# Synonymize [serverside] with [server-side]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

I think [serverside](/questions/tagged/serverside) (109) should merged and set as synonym to [server-side](/questions/tagged/server-side) (535).

What does the community think?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Thank you, sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed: [serverside](/questions/tagged/serverside) to [server-side](/questions/tagged/server-side)